# Why is the Doppler angle setting supposed to be 60 degrees for arteries but 0 degrees for veins?

Tags: medical-imaging, radiology, ultrasounds

In ultrasonography, why isn't the Doppler angle correction supposed to be 60 degrees for veins just like it is for arteries?

Comment: What is your source for this?

Comment: Just from reading up on the subject online. I haven't found it explained why.

Comment: Then how do you know it's true? I didn't ask for an explanation why. I just asked where you read this.